# Trim link to root domain from macros with php regex (look inside)

Tags: php, regex, macros, preg-replace, preg-match

My php script contains macros ===shortlink===. This macros sits into EOF container

```
<?php
$gtemplate=<<<EOF
 ===shortlink===
EOF;
?>
```

===shortlink=== contains url like this http://site.com/2012/blog-post.html
When I run the script it shows result from ===shortlink=== . URL like `http://site.com/2012/blog-post.html`. 
I
 need to trim url from this macros to show only domain name as site.com. Suggest me how to trim it in this macros with php regex?

Looks like this macros should be returned to special var , then trimmed then returned back to ====shortlink===. 
Hey, masters do you beat it?

tried something like this

```
$urlpage = '===shortlink===';
preg_match_all("/((?:[a-z][a-z\\.\\d\\-]+)\\.(?:[a-z][a-z\\-]+))(?![\\w\\.])/", $urlpage, $replurl, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

    $replurl= '===shortlink===';
```

but it  doesn't work. please help me with this simple replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `parse_url()`?

```
<?php
    $url = "http://site.com/2012/blog-post.html";

    $parsed = parse_url($url);
    echo $parsed["host"];
```

Comment: Thank, but i need to return trimmed url as macros ===shortlink=== again to call it in container.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what output you're expecting. You said you wanted the host, ie. `site.com`, this is what you got. Do you want anything else? If so, specify it exactly.

Comment: macros ===shortlink=== containes url itself. I want to replace url from it to just domain and return result to ===shortlink=== back.

Comment: Please explain the meaning of ===shortlink=== I still haven't figured out what the hell is it.

Comment: shortlink is url itself http://site.com/2012/blog-post.html . this macros grows from var but i have not access to it (zended). so i need to extract result from this macros ===shortlink====. this will be http://site.com/2012/blog-post.html trim it to site.com and return to this macros back. so ===shortlink=== should become site.com

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see the complete working code by: ctrtard.com with special thanks.

```
<?php
function trim_url_to_root_domain($target) {
/* Usage:
* echo trim_url_to_root_domain("http://mytarget.com");
* or
* echo ucfirst(trim_url_to_root_domain("http://mytarget.com")); // uppercase first letter
*/
    // trim http, https, and //
    $target = str_replace("http:", "", $target);
    $target = str_replace("https:", "", $target);
    $target = str_replace("//", "", $target);

    // check for dots
    $dots = substr_count($target, '.');
    if ($dots > 1) { // if there are more than 1 dots, we need to remove subdomain
        $first_dot = strpos ($target, ".");
        $target = substr($target, $first_dot+1, strlen($target));
    }

    // find the last slash, this should be the slash just before directory info
    $last_slash = strripos($target, "/");
    if ($last_slash > 0 ) {
        $target = substr($target, 0, $last_slash);
    }

    // find last slash one more time, to handle targets like /domain.com
    $last_slash = strripos($target, "/");
    if ($last_slash !== FALSE ) {
        $target = substr($target, 1, strlen($target));
    }

    // normalize target so it's all lower case
    $target = strtolower($target);

    return $target;
}


echo trim_url_to_root_domain("http://mytarget.com");

echo ucfirst(trim_url_to_root_domain("http://mytarget.com"));
?>
```